# How to host a torrent server?

Tags: apache-http-server, bittorrent, http

I use Apache on my machine to share some files over office network.

How can I host them over torrent instead of sending them over http?

Comment: But torrents are illegal!

Comment: What? its just a protocol.. how can a protocol be illegal?

Comment: Torrents are not a protocol, but BitTorrrent is. Some USA courts have shut down torrent servers/sites based on their ruling that hosting torrents that link to illegal content shared by others is in fact illegal....http://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2011/01/mpaa-shuts-down-50-torrent-sites.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a torrent server - you can create a [torrent](http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/) using your torrent client, add a [tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker) to improve reliability and then share it. You could probably use the apache server as a webseed - but you're trying not to use the web server, right?

In this specific case though, the speeds you get over the office network are likely to be faster than using torrents - you MIGHT be able to use a local tracker, and have it serve out local IP addresses, but its still not going to be very efficient. torrents are designed for anonymous, high reliability sharing at decent speeds - regular file sharing over lan might end up being faster.

I'd suggest looking at [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav) or [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead.

If you want it *really* fast.. nothing beats good ol [sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)