# How can I stream video directly from torrent file?

Tags: linux, video-streaming

Is there some way to do live stream video directly from torrent ?
Are there linux tools like torrent cleint which can do this?

I need to do something like [uTorrent Video Stream](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-adds-video-streaming-support-091217/)

Comment: Are you asking how to program this or if there is already some program that does this? And what do you understand under livestream? Playing a video live at loading that was saved on other computers or streaming the video live from your computer to others?

Comment: Wether this is possible depends on the contents of the file. Not all video files are playable without the entire file, and if it is compressed it will definitly not work.

Comment: I need to use some kind of linux tools (programs) to stream torrent while he is downloading. NOT to download all torrent and stream after that!

Comment: It depends on the file content if what you want to do is possible.

Comment: This Question on SU: > http://superuser.com/questions/305691/i-am-using-a-p2p-website-why-is-there-data-being-uploaded asked about *streaming* from a torrent file, so it apparently **is** possible.

Answer (score 3):

Torrents aren't downloaded in order, so can't be streamed.

Comment: I need something like stream functionality in latest "uTorrent" client but for Linux. [see that](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-adds-video-streaming-support-091217/)

Comment: This is wrong. You can download the torrent in sequential order. qbittorrent does that and is my favourite torrent client.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to stream content using bittorrent in linux. You can use [btcat](http://p2ptube.sourceforge.net/#btcat) to do it.

Comment: `Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` too old sadly

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that. The torrent protocol relies on the use of peers / seeds, therefore availability cannot be guaranteed. Some torrent clients (utorrent etc.) do allow you to "preview" the file as it is downloading though, but that basically just plays back what has already downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

I am using qbittorrent. Add your torrent, right click on desired file, choose "download in sequential order", let it download for a while, then choose preview.

or you can play using vlc, instead of preview. it will require you to run via console specifying file and play option.

Answer (score 1):

[Peerflix](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix) streams torrents to a media player easily and runs on all platforms supported by Node.js. To install on Ubuntu: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/peerflix-stream-torrents-with-vlc-or.html